# Python: How to read all text file contents in multiple folders and save them into one excel file

Tags: python, excel, text, xlwt

I am currently working on this task and got stuck. Please give me your advices. The code I am writing below, it returns only the .txt file name from multiple folders, while I would like to print out the content of each .txt file and save in different rows in excel. The contents of each .txt file are numbers.

```
import os, glob,xlwt
#create workbook and worksheet
wbk = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = wbk.add_sheet('data')
path= 'E:\Cag\Data'
row = 0
for dir,subdir,files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        if glob.fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.txt'):
            L = file.strip()
            sheet.write(row,5,L)
            row += 1
wbk.save('read_all_txt_in_folders.xls')
print 'success'
```

Comment: you should import directly fnmatch, instead of using it from glob.

Comment: What do you think `L = file.strip()` will do?

Comment: Please don't use built-in function names (`file`) as a variable name.  It's confusing to people reading your program.  Also, upper-case variable names (`L`) are confusing.  Finally, single-letter variables names are confusing.  Please use meaningful, lower-case names.

Comment: thanks for your advice. I used the L= file.strip() to list the .txt file contents into columns in excel, with out that I think it is not going to work. If you have other way of writing it. Please help me

Comment: "to list the .txt file contents".  Do you mean "read the contents"?  If so, you should check the Python documentation for how file objects work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you see the file names because you write them. `L` contains the file name. (And the `L = file.strip()` seems unnecessary to me.)

If you want to write the file contents, you should do instead `L = open(os.path.join(dir, file), "r").read()`.

Comment: yeah, this is exactly what I want. I tried it and it returned this error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\read_all_txt_in_folders.py", line 15, in <module>
    L = open(file, 'r').read()
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ttt.txt'. The ttt.txt is in the folder, why this error is printed. Thanks

Comment: IIRC you need to contatenate `dir` (or `subdir`?) and `file` to get full path.

Comment: `walk()` yields its stuff (`subdir` and `files`) relative to the subdirectory it is currently in (`dir`). So you have to `os.path.join(dir, file)` to get the correct path. Sorry, I forgot that in my answer (-> just edited). (Besides, it is bad style to use a variable name `dir` as it hides the built-in with the same name.)

Comment: @glglgl: Thank you so much for your explanation. It works now, but the contents of those txt files(let say 100 rows of numbers/ .txt file) are saved now in excel format in rows. But I want them saved in columns. I used .strip() in my initial code and it stripped the contents of text files from top to bottom.

Comment: -1: This leaves files open.  For a small set of files that's not a problem.  For a large collection of files, that will be a problem.

Comment: Normally, the files are gc'ed away. But you are right - this is not guaranteed, so better close them explicitly (with `close()` or with `with`).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to write the file contents, you should do instead

```
with open(os.path.join(dir, file), "r") as source:
    L= source.read()
```

This assures that the file is actually closed when you're done reading them.  That releases system resources.